# Merge strings together until a symbol occurs

Tags: python

Merging string together in list until a symbol occured in the string.

```
names = ['My name is john.', 'My', 'name', 'is Andrew.']
```

`"My name is john."` is correct

how to concatenate: `"My name is Andrew."`? knowing that the list might be different.

```
symbols = ['.', ':']
for i in range(len(names)-1):
   if names[i][-1] not in symbols:
      print(names[i] + ' ' + names[i+1])
```

tried this one is working but not how I want to be.

Does anyone has any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the `end` optional parameter of `print()`.

```
names = ['My name is john.', 'My', 'name', 'is Andrew.']
symbols = ['.', ':']
for phrase in names:
    print(phrase, end=" ")
    if (phrase[-1] in symbols):
        print()
```

Output:

```
My name is john. 
My name is Andrew.
```

If you want to store them in a list you can easily use two different list:

```
names = ['My name is john.', 'My', 'name', 'is Andrew.']
symbols = ['.', ':']
phrases = []
current = []
for phrase in names:
    current.append(phrase)
    if (phrase[-1] in symbols):
        phrases.append(" ".join(current))
        current = []
print(phrases)
```

Output:

```
['My name is john.', 'My name is Andrew.']
```

Using a single list we can do:

```
names = ['My name is john.', 'My', 'name', 'is Andrew.']
symbols = ['.', ':']
phrases = [""]
for phrase in names:
    phrases[-1] += phrase
    if (phrase[-1] in symbols):
        phrases.append("")
del phrases[-1] # Remove the last empty append
print(phrases)
```

Output:

```
['My name is john.', 'Mynameis Andrew.']
```

Or if you like [`Regular Expresions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re
names = ['My name is john.', 'My', 'name', 'is Andrew.']
print([phrase.strip() for phrase in re.split(r"[\.:]", " ".join(names))[:-1]])
```

Output:

```
['My name is john', 'My name is Andrew']
```

To accept some edge cases:

```
results = [phrase.strip() for phrase in re.split(r"[\.:]", " ".join(names))[:-1]]
if (results[-1] == ""):
    del results[-1]
print(results)
```

Using:

```
>>> ['My name is john.', 'My', 'name', 'is Andrew.', 'test test']
['My name is john', 'My name is Andrew', 'test test']
```

To preserve the `.` and `:` you should use [@Jon clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) comment:

```
import re
names = ['My name is john.', 'My', 'name', 'is Andrew.']
print([phrase.strip() for phrase in re.findall('(.*?[:.])', ' '.join(names))])
```

Output:

```
['My name is john.', 'My name is Andrew.']
```

To accept some edge cases:

```
results = [phrase.strip() for phrase in re.findall('(.*?[:.])', ' '.join(names)) if phrase]
if (results[-1] in [".", ":"]):
    del results[-1]
else:
    results[-1] = results[-1][:-1]
print(results)
```

Using:

```
>>> ['My name is john.', 'My', 'name', 'is Andrew.', 'test test']
['My name is john.', 'My name is Andrew.', 'test test']
```

Comment: yes, using print, I understand, but let's say store it back into the list?

Comment: @Michael ok, give me a minute

Comment: Thankss, I have a small question too, what's your email address?

Comment: @Michael, If you don't mind I would prefer to not give you my email. But if you have any question you can ping me (use @ followed by my name) in a Stack Overflow chat and I will receive a notification about it.

Comment: @EnderLook regex wise, I was thinking of `re.findall('(.*?[:.])', ' '.join(names))`... that way you can preserve the character in the string more conveniently than split.

Comment: The output that gives you is `'My name is Andrew.'` btw.. think you copied/pasted the wrong output lline... also, just thought it might not give correct results if `names` ends with something that doesn't have an expected character... eg: `names = ['My name is john.', 'My', 'name', 'is Andrew.', 'test test']` - won't include the "test test" stuff

Comment: @JonClements, Oh, I haven't thought in that case

Comment: I like this answer a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
names = ['My name is john.', 'My', 'name', 'is Andrew.']
symbols = ['.', ':']
for i in names:
   if(i[-1] in symbols):
      print(i)
   else:
      print(i,end=" ")
```

If you are expecting your output like :

```
My name is john.
My name is Andrew.
```

Please always provide a complete question. Your question is a bit unclear.